# has microwave safe plastic plate gone bad

Tags: microwave, reheating, heat

I used my microwave oven to reheat [Vermicelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermicelli).

The plate was hot and the plate's centre side got bulged up a bit ( i mean noticeable level ), I never saw this before.

[image]

I used microwave safe plastic

[image]

I'm wondering the vermicelli heated up due to microwave cooking and because the vermicelli is hot and plate started heating up and the microwave safe plastic plate got bulged up a bit.

Plenty of times I've heard microwave-oven causing cancer. But I just want to be sure.

Should I ever reuse the plate ? or should I ever not reheat a vermicelli in a plastic plate ? or Can the above scenario is injurious to health.

Microwave oven was on for just one minute only

Update:

please find some of the other plastic based microwave safe products that I use below

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

FYI:

This is the microwave oven that I use

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To get one thing out of the way, there is not a single case of a microwave-oven having caused cancer on its own. Ever. It's just not how microwaves work. At the frequency that the electromagnetic waves are emitted by the ovens, it's not possible for it to cause cancer even if the unit were defective and leaking. Furthermore, there are no lingering microwaves or radiation on the food ([well, apart from what was already there](https://www.epa.gov/radtown/natural-radioactivity-food)) that could cause cancer because, again, that's just not how microwaves work.

This is a myth that has been perpetuated for decades that has no basis in reality (likely because some scientist made the mistake of saying it operated using "micro-wave radiation" in public during the time when everyone was paranoid of nuclear war). The worst thing that can happen is you can get a severe burn if you were directly exposed to the microwaves for too long (which you would definitely notice).

---

Now, as far as the plate is concerned, I'm assuming that this plate is [one of these Signoraware plates on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00JJH1OVY). The description says they are made of polypropylene (confirmed by the recycling ID code 5 on the plate), which is said to be microwave-safe at temperatures up to 250 °C before warping. It's possible that the steam formed from surface water trapped under the vermicelli in contact with the plate super-heated to those temperatures which caused the warping.

From this point, I'm going to separate my answer into the objective and subjective sections as I'm having troubles finding any definitive answer one way or the other:

- **Objectively**, there is likely nothing wrong with the plate - it's just a bit disfigured. The only real danger is that, if it continues to warp multiple times, it can become brittle leading to surface cracks and, ultimately, breakage. But for the time being, as long as the warping doesn't bother you too much, you can just keep using the plate as normal. In the future you should create a well in the center of the food you are reheating so as to limit how much heat can build up in one place, and that should help keep this from happening again.
- **Subjectively** (and take this with a grain of salt because, again, I cannot find a definitive answer on this from a reputable source), I would throw it out. When plastic warps, it's often a sign that it has begun to break down, and from that point on it can leech into whatever food it comes in contact with. I have no idea if polypropylene follows this trend and to what degree, but [a recent study](https://www.nature.com/articles/s43016-020-00171-y) has found that it has a tendency to leech microplastics into warm/hot beverages, so I imagine the problem is exacerbated when the polypropylene has been heated to the point that it has begun warping. I'm not sure I would trust the plate any more than I would trust a Teflon non-stick pan that's been destroyed by the frequent use of metal utensils over time.

Comment: I'd be more concerned that the plate would warp further and even crack, making a mess.

Comment: @FuzzyChef That's also a distinct possibility, though I would think that the plate would get visible surface cracks long before it actually snaps in two, which would be a clear indication that it's time to stop using it. YMMV, though.

Comment: @Abion47 - Thanks for the answer, It helps. One thing what material should we use for reheating ? when it comes to plate , So far whatever Items I buy , I check and see if it's microwave safe then I buy. I'm not seeing any guidelines on how to use it.. less there should be less water or something like that

Comment: @Abion47 - I have updated my question with some of the other microwave safe products based on plastic. Could you help me understand the healthy way to use these products inside microwave oven.

Comment: @Vivo I'm hardly an expert on the matter (as evidenced by my disclaimer in my answer), so I can only make educated guesses. I'd wager that anything made out of glass or ceramic (assuming stable dyes/enamels were used) would be fine to use in the microwave since it would take temperatures far hotter than a microwave was capable of putting out before they started to break down. And in the unlikely event that trace amounts do get in your food, they are basically harmless. (Trace amounts of glass not to be confused with shards of glass, mind you. I'm talking about microscopic amounts.)

Comment: Thanks , that's helpful

Comment: Now there's evidence that microwaving food in plastic containers releases quite some microplastics into the food https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.est.3c01942

Comment: @FuzzyChef with some plastics, cracking is quite likely after deformation, but PP isn't that brittle at or above room temperature. It does become brittle in a freezer, so reusing thin  PP takeaway containers for freezing leftovers eventually breaks them

Comment: @Abion47 Ceramics in the microwave are a complicated topic (I'm a potter).  TL;DR is that some are OK and some aren't.